# Get the current directory of my exe, even when it is launched from another app or shortcut

Tags: c#, winforms

**Solved.**

I found out that the "StartIn" variable of a shortcut directly affects the result of the current working directory. That is why no matter what I change in the code or the method I use to find the current directory, the result always says the shortcut's directory.

---

I am currently trying to get the directory of my exe. I am using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)` to do that. The problem is that the directory it returns is the directory of the shortcut or app that launched it. While I need the directory of the actual executable.

Tried methods:

- `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)`
- `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`
- `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`
- `AppContext.BaseDirectory`
- `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: AppContext.BaseDirectory | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory?view=net-6.0

Comment: @RandRandom Doesn't work, returns the directory of the shortcut that launched it

Comment: highly doubt that is correct, as that would mean it would try to load referenced dlls from the location of the shortcut

Comment: @RandRandom I tried it with a test program that just prints AppContext.BaseDirectory. And I setup a shortcut in desktop, and it printed out my desktop path.

Comment: string path = Environment .CurrentDirectory;

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 Same problem.

Comment: share your code then only find solutions.

Comment: edited my answer based on your "solved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already said in the comments `AppContext.BaseDirectory` has to return the correct path, you are doing something that is unknown to us.

Here a proof that it is working as expected

My WinForms application consists of this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
    }
}
```

Here a screenshot as proof:

[image]

Then I went ahead and created a shortcut next to the solution:

[image]

When I double click the shortcut, a message box pops up with the following content:

[image]

As you can see it is as expected the Debug location and not the solution file location.

Edit:

Also changing "ausführen in" (maybe "start in" or "run in" in english) does NOT contribute to the described behaviour for `AppContext.BaseDirectory`, as you can see here:

[image]